# How to embed external code to Android app?

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-follow

I want to post a button like follow me on twitter

here is code

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://www.twpics.com/BUTTON6/twitbutton.swf" width="140" height="62"><param name="movie" value="http://www.twpics.com/BUTTON6/twitbutton.swf"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><param name="menu" value="false"></param><param name="wmode" value="transparent"></param><param name="flashvars" value="username=ksreddisri"></param><a href="http://www.gamblinginsider.ca/casino-games/" title="find casino games at GamblingInsider">find casino games at GamblingInsider</a><embed src="http://www.twpics.com/BUTTON6/twitbutton.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" width="140" height="62" menu="false" wmode="transparent" flashvars="username=ksreddisri"></embed></object>
```

how to embed the above code in my android app,please help to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am almost certain you can't directly. What you should do, if you have to go that way, is to to use WebView and display HTML page with your flash object. Be aware flash is not avilable for Android 4.1 (Jelly Bean), Flash player is optional (so people may not have it). I strongly suggest not going Flash way on Android.

Comment: can you giva me an example please.